# Смена цвета при клике и обратно

Tags: javascript

Как сделать данное действие?

```js
  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        document.getElementById('game').innerHTML += '<div class="block"><div>';
    }
    document.getElementById('game').onclick = function (event) {
        console.log(event);
        if (event.target.className=='block') {
            event.target.innerHTML = ""
        }
    }
```

```css
#game { 
width: 200px; 
height: 200px; 
background: orangered;
 } 
.block { 
width: 50px; 
height: 50px; 
float: left; 
border: 1px solid white; 
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
    
</div>
```

Пытаюсь сделать сетку 4 на 4, и чтобы при клике менялся цвет элемента, а при еще одном клике возвращался.

Comment: Я так понимаю, цвета у Вас зашиты в стилях? Если - да, добавьте их сюда

Comment: #game {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orangered;
}
.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid white;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

Answer (score 2):

```js
  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        document.getElementById('game').innerHTML += '<div class="block"><div>';
    }
    document.getElementById('game').onclick = function (event) {
        var target = event.target;
        if (target.className=='block') {
            var color = getComputedStyle(target).backgroundColor;
             if (color == "rgb(0, 0, 0)"){
                target.style.backgroundColor = ""
             } else {
                 event.target.style.backgroundColor= "black"
              }
           
        }
    }
```

```css
#game { 
width: 200px; 
height: 200px; 
background: orangered;
 } 
.block { 
width: 50px; 
height: 50px; 
float: left; 
border: 1px solid white; 
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
    
</div>
```

Comment: как раз делал. Смотрите

Comment: спасибо мужик! getComputedStyle(target).backgroundColor - че то сложно,пойду гуглить за эту тему